How to select sample for A/B Testing with High Correlated Models
Hi I'm performing an a/b test between two machine learning models that give a score for each customer. The models have  high correlation. I'm worried that if take model A, select the sample and afterwards select the sample for model B for example this can generate bias in my test ( the remaining population will have customers with low "quality" because the models have high correlation).
Any ideas on how to overcome this? I would appreciate any references too.

Can you provide more details on the model, how it is being evaluated, and the design of the experiment?
